# How to use 'showStatus()' method in java app without dealing with applets?

Tags: java, applet

I'm reading an old java textbook(DEITEL by the way) that use applets so much in its code . I tried to ignore everything about applets and go on . but I got stuck now ! it seems that showStatus() method cant be used in java application , can be ?

```java
public void dialogmessage(){

     if(gameStatus == CONTINUE){
         showStatus("Roll again");
     }
}
```

Is there anything else can be used rather than this method ?

Comment: *"it seems that showStatus() method cant be used in java application"*  Given it is supposed to show the message in the status line of the **browser** that hosts the applet, it makes sense it is not defined for applications, which are not embedded in a browser.  But it is possible to add a method to the GUI class that replaces it, so long as the GUI has a `Label`/`JLabel` in the `PAGE_END` of a `BorderLayout`.  Is this GUI using Swing or AWT?

Comment: BTW - that book is too old to be of much (good) use.  Find newer tutorials such as [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Comment: Andrew , after I had taken the first lesson from website you gave me , I must have SERIOUS CONVERSION WITH YOU!! , about the old-fashioned way and new-fashioned of creating GUI :) . the first question is : as expert java dev. (that is from your numerous reputation) , Do you often create your GUI by source code or by drag-and-drop way